# Rを使ってあるpdfのテキスト情報が読み込めません。原因がわかりません。

Tags: r, pdf

神奈川県のサイトから感染者の情報を取得しているのですが、(市区町村単位のデータがほしいため）
https://www.pref.kanagawa.jp/docs/ga4/covid19/occurrence_24.html
にある
4月2日の川崎市の情報(https://www.pref.kanagawa.jp/documents/74417/20210402_kawasaki.pdf)を取得できません。
他の日時のデータは取得できていました。

```
library(pdftools)
path<-"https://www.pref.kanagawa.jp/documents/74417/20210402_kawasaki.pdf"
pdf_text(path)
[1] "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

というように読み込まれています。
テキスト情報を読み込めない理由がわからなかったため、質問しました。原因がわかる方がいましたら教えて頂きたいです。
通常は以下のようになります。

```
path<-"https://www.pref.kanagawa.jp/documents/74417/20210401_kawasaki.pdf"
pdf_text(path)
[1] "                                     令和３年４月１日\r\n                                     報道 発表資 料\r\n  新型コロナウイルス感染症患者等の発生について\r\n 川崎市内において、新型コロナウイルスに感染した患者等が確認されました。
```

追記
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
RStudio Version 1.3.959
を使用しています。

Comment: うまくいっている他日のデータのURLは何ですか？うまくいっているpdfとうまくいっていない20210401_kawasaki.pdfをブラウザで開いて、違いを確認してはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 少なくともこの PDF ファイルは画像を PDF に変換しているのでテキスト情報が含まれていません(おそらく紙の書類をスキャンして PDF 化したものと思われます。)。

Comment: 少し調べてみましたが、内容が同じ https://www.city.kawasaki.jp/350/cmsfiles/contents/0000115/115886/20210402.pdf はテキストを抽出する事が可能です。

Comment: 神奈川県のサイトにあるhttps://www.pref.kanagawa.jp/documents/74417/20210402_kawasaki.pdfのほうはブラウザで開くとURL(20210402_kawasaki.pdf)とpdf本体?の名前（20210402.pdf）が異なっていたのそれが原因かもしれません。川崎市の方のURLでやってみます。ありがとうございます！